# How to use "OR" for comparing strings in Swift

Tags: swift, operators

I wish to check if the value of a variable -  aVar  is equal to one of several letters:

```
if aVar != "S" || "X" {println("NO")}
```

This gives the error:

> Binary operator || cannot be applied to operands of type String

A very minor question but can't find an answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if `aVar` is either S or X:

```
if (aVar=="S")||(aVar=="X") {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator expects its left-hand and right-hand sides to both be boolean expressions. You've provided `aVar != "S"` on the left but only `"X"` on the right. Try:

```
if aVar == "S" || aVar == "X" {
  println ("NO")
}
```

Note that you said "is equal to one of ..." but you used `!=` (not equal to) in your code.  Not sure which you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that swift is a type safe language so:

```
if aVar != "S" || "X" {println("NO")}
```

Won't work. On the other hand, in order to get the above code to work all you have to do is reuse the `aVar` name like:

```
if (aVar != "S" || aVar != "X") {println("NO")}
```

cheers

Comment: `(aVar != "S" || aver != "X")` is *always* true :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let aVar = "someStringValue"

if aVar == "S" || aVar == "X" {
    print("String: '\(aVar)' is equal to one or both of these strings.")
} else {
    print("String: '\(aVar)' doesn't equal to at least one of these strings.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using arrays:

```
if !contains(["S", "X"], aVar) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This really looks nice and simple,  thanks will try this out.

Comment: your suggestion resulted in:   which worked fine

func checkAns (answerCheckArray:[String], ans:String) ->String{
  var result:String!
  if contains(answerCheckArray, Ans1[0].text) {
   result = "OK"
  }else{
   result = "Wrong"
  Ans1[0].text = ""
  }
 return result
Must still try the set suggestion
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of answers already, but none of them is using the obvious when testing for multiple values: A set.

```
let matchingSet : Set<Character> = ["S", "X", "M", "G"]

let char : Character = "A"
if matchingSet.contains(char) {
    // Do something
}
```

Using a set, the complexity is always `O(1)` whereas using multiple `OR` statements or an array has a worst complexity of `O(n)`. Of course when you just need to check against 2 values, you shouldn't use a set, because that makes your code less readable. The more values you have, the more I recommend to use a set instead.

Comment: I will try the set idea  - as I want to create a generic func so I can test a variety of  answers to different questions the set could work well. Thanks